# Creating Sharepoint Directory Recurisvely

Tags: sharepoint, recursion

I am attempting to create a set of folders that comes in from a flat file in the manner of.

X/Y/Z

and I would like to create a directory for each of these but my memory of recursion has got me in knotts.

here is my code can someone advise.

```
    public void CreateDirectory(SPFolderCollection oWeb, string folder)
    {
        SPFolder theFolder = oWeb.Add(folder);
        theFolder.Update();
    }

    public void FolderCreator(SPWeb oWeb)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(this.txtFolders.Text);
        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {
            string folderLine = reader.ReadLine();
            if (folderLine.Contains("/"))
            {
                SPFolderCollection collection = oWeb.Folders["Documents"].SubFolders[folderLine.Split('/')[0]].SubFolders;
                CreateDirectory(collection, folderLine);
            }
            SPFolderCollection newCollection = oWeb.Folders["Documents"].SubFolders;
            CreateDirectory(newCollection, folderLine);
        }
    }
```

This does not work I am looking for it to do recrusion so if I pass

ABC/DEF/GHI
and 
ABC/DEF
it will go and create the folders appropriately.

But I am stuck as how to do that.

Comment: what is your question/problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SPFileCollection.Add()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms414180) methods allow you to pass in the full relative path of a file.  So this may be an option assuming you aren't just generating a folder structure, which you may be doing, in which case this won't really work unless you create a temporary file and then delete it to keep the folder path.

```
web.Files.Add("/sites/somesite/shared documents/foldera/folderb/folderc/somefile.txt", stream);
```